# Changing netgear router telnet root password

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a Netgear JNR1010 router but I am not able to change the router's root password. Router Firmware Version is 1.0.0.18

I tried multiple commands in the Busybox console that came up,

```
BusyBox v1.6.1 (2013-06-09 15:21:35 HKT) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

# chpasswd
-sh: chpasswd: not found

# <tab>
[                  grep               mkdir              siproxd
[[                 halt               mknod              sleep
arp                ifconfig           modprobe           start-stop-daemon
arping             igmpproxyv3        mount              straceroute
ash                inadyn             msntp              tar
auth               inetd              nbnslisten         tc
bing               init               nbsmtp             telnetd
brctl              insmod             nbtscan            test
busybox            ip                 netstat            tftp
cat                iptables           pc                 tftpd
cp                 iwcontrol          peanuthullc2       traceroute
date               iwpriv             ping               true
diag               kill               poweroff           udhcpc
dproxy             killall            pppd               udhcpc-discovery
echo               klogd              pppoe-discovery    udhcpd
egrep              l2tpd              pptp               udhcpplus
ethtool            logic              pptp_discovery     umount
fgrep              login              protest            upgrader
flash              logmonitor         ps                 upnp.sh
flash_test         ls                 reboot             vconfig
flush_conntrack    lsmod              ripd               watchdog
free               md5sum             rm                 wget
fuser              mesg               rmmod              wscd
getopt             mini_httpd         route              zebra
getsmaps           miniupnpd          sh

# busybox
BusyBox v1.6.1 (2013-06-09 15:21:35 HKT) multi-call binary
Copyright (C) 1998-2006   Erik Andersen, Rob Landley, and others.
Licensed under GPLv2.   See source distribution for full notice.

Usage: busybox [function] [arguments]...
   or: [function] [arguments]...

    BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
    utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
    link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
    will act like whatever it was invoked as!

Currently defined functions:
    [, [[, arp, arping, ash, cat, cp, date, echo, egrep, fgrep,
    free, fuser, getopt, grep, halt, ifconfig, inetd, init,
    insmod, kill, killall, klogd, linuxrc, login, ls, lsmod,
    md5sum, mesg, mkdir, mknod, modprobe, mount, netstat,
    ping, poweroff, ps, reboot, rm, rmmod, route, sh, sleep,
    start-stop-daemon, straceroute, tar, telnetd, test, tftp,
    traceroute, true, umount, vconfig, watchdog, wget
```

Can anyone please help me on how to change my root password or shutdown the telnet service. I searched for options in the web interface but to no avail.

Please note that I do not want to change the default firmware due to warranty issues.

Comment: I need an answer as soon as possible since my network is now vulnerable. Will upvote any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that You cant use the **passwd** command in busybox. Then You should edit the file **/etc/passwd** or the **/etc/shadow** file. Or more easy, you can try change it from the admin webpage.
You should be noted that in the *passwd* file and *shadow* the password is an hash of the key.

Comment: I am not able to change it even now... the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow are located on a squashfs read only file system

Comment: IN that case you will need to flash the firmware. Even if only with all the same settings bar the password file.